# Sum data for each date in column

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a column with date

```
01-june-16.    Cashier1.     100.      36
01-june-16.    Cashier2.     300.      58
02-juns-16.    Cashier1.     500.      36
02-june-16.    Cashiet1.     200.      65 
02-june-16.    Cashier2.     100.      54
```

I need to add the data for each cashier in the corresponding rows for each date so on June first I should have (136+358) for that day's transactions.

Comment: Note that for 01-june-16 the total is 100.36+300.58. Also why using VBA? This can be easily achieved with a formula (see SUMIFS)

Comment: Because there is a lot of data and i want to create a form and use a command button to run through the data and do it automatically

Answer (score 2):

Try this code let me know if it works.

```
Sub RunSubtotal()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim MaxRow As Long, I As Long
Dim Tot As Double
Dim Dte As String

Set WS = ActiveSheet
MaxRow = WS.Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Tot = 0

'---> Clear Col C
WS.Range("C:C").ClearContents

'---> Sort Worksheet by Date
WS.UsedRange.Sort key1:=WS.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Dte = WS.Cells(1, "A")

'---> Start Process
For I = 1 To MaxRow + 1
If WS.Range("A" & I) <> Dte Then
    WS.Cells(I - 1, "C") = Tot
    Dte = WS.Cells(I, "A")
    Tot = 0
End If

Tot = Tot + Val(WS.Cells(I, "B"))

Next I

MsgBox ("Totals inserted in Col C by date successfully.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Question says <each date is a new column> which it seems to be a mistake and should corresponds to rows instead of columns. Nevertheless you have not asked for clarifications on that before writing the code.

Comment: Im sorry i meant each date is a new row so there is only one column with date for the month

Answer (score 0):

I propose two solutions using the `SUMIF` formula, avoiding the use of `For...Next`, setting the required values at once. Both offer the choice of keeping the formula or the values returned by the formula.

Assumptions:

- Data start at `B2`
- Data has the following headers: Date, Cashier, Amount
- Adding headers: Total.Daily to show the required results
- The second solution assumes a summary of the results starts at `G2:G3`

*Before applying solutions*
[image]

1.- Totals in Data range

```
Sub Adding_Amount_by_Date()
Const kFmlTotDay As String = "=SUMIF(#rDate,#Date,#rAmount)"            'SUMIF formula to apply
Dim rDta As Range
Dim sFml As String
Dim rTmp As Range, sFld As String, bPos As Byte

    Rem Set Data Range
    Set rDta = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("B2").CurrentRegion    'Update as required

    Rem Working With Body Range (Data Range excluding Headers)
    With rDta.Offset(1).Resize(-1 + rDta.Rows.Count)

        Rem Reset Formula
        sFml = kFmlTotDay

        Rem Amount Range
        sFld = "Amount"                                                 'Update as required
        bPos = WorksheetFunction.Match(sFld, rDta.Rows(1), 0)
        Set rTmp = .Columns(bPos)
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#r" & sFld, rTmp.Address)

        Rem Date Range
        sFld = "Date"                                                   'Update as required
        bPos = WorksheetFunction.Match(sFld, rDta.Rows(1), 0)
        Set rTmp = .Columns(bPos)
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#r" & sFld, rTmp.Address)
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#" & sFld, rTmp.Cells(1).Address(0, 1))

        Rem Enter Daily Total (Formula or Value)
        sFld = "Total.Daily"                                            'Update as required
        bPos = WorksheetFunction.Match(sFld, rDta.Rows(1), 0)
        .Columns(bPos).Formula = sFml                                   'Enter formula
        .Columns(bPos).Value = .Columns(bPos).Value2                    'Replace formula with values (comment this line to have keep the formulas)

    End With

End Sub
```

2.- Total in Summary Range

```
Sub Adding_Amount_by_Date_OutputRange()
Const kFmlTotDay As String = "=SUMIF(#rDate,#Date,#rAmount)"            'SUMIF formula to apply
Dim rOut As Range
Dim rDta As Range
Dim sFml As String
Dim rTmp As Range, sFld As String, bPos As Byte

    Rem Reset Output Table Range
    Set rOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("G2").CurrentRegion    'Update as required
    With rOut
        If .Rows.Count > 1 Then
            .Offset(1).Resize(-1 + rOut.Rows.Count).ClearContents
        Set rOut = rOut.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    End If
    End With

    Rem Set Data Range
    Set rDta = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("B2").CurrentRegion    'Update as required

    Rem Work With Data Range Body (excluding Headers)
    With rDta.Offset(1).Resize(-1 + rDta.Rows.Count)

        Rem Reset Formula
        sFml = kFmlTotDay

        Rem Amount Range
        sFld = "Amount"                                                 'Update as required
        bPos = WorksheetFunction.Match(sFld, rDta.Rows(1), 0)
        Set rTmp = .Columns(bPos)
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#r" & sFld, rTmp.Address)

        Rem Date Range
        sFld = "Date"                                                   'Update as required
        bPos = WorksheetFunction.Match(sFld, rDta.Rows(1), 0)
        Set rTmp = .Columns(bPos)
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#r" & sFld, rTmp.Address)
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#" & sFld, rOut.Cells(2, 1).Address(0, 1))

    End With

    Rem List Unique Date in Output Range
    With rOut
        rDta.Columns(bPos).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CriteriaRange:=rDta.Columns(bPos), _
            CopyToRange:=.Cells(1), _
            Unique:=True
        .Worksheet.Names("Criteria").Delete
        .Worksheet.Names("Extract").Delete
    End With

    Rem Enter Daily Total (Formula or Value)
    Set rOut = rOut.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    With rOut.Offset(1).Resize(-1 + rOut.Rows.Count).Columns(2)
        .Formula = sFml                                                 'Enter formula
        .Value = .Columns(bPos).Value2                                  'Replace formula with values (comment this line to have keep the formulas)
    End With

    End Sub
```

*After applying both solutions*
[image]

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Excel functions (by category)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5F91F4E9-7B42-46D2-9BD1-63F26A86C0EB), [Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html), [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx),

[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), [WorksheetFunction Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx), [With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)